# NodeJS convert request body to uppercase and return in response

Tags: node.js, sails.js

With below code I planned to convert req body to uppercase and return in res and also print it stdout, when I test res is never fetched, and http connection is alive forever.  Please can someone point the mistake here.

```
var http =require('http'); 
var fs = require('fs');
var through = require('through2');

var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
             if(req.method==='POST'){
                req.pipe(through(function(buffer,encoding,next){
                        //console.log()
                        this.push(buffer.toString().toUpperCase());
                        next();
                    })).pipe(process.stdout).pipe(res) // If remove .pipe(process.stdout) then I get response.

             }
             //res.end(); -- If I enable this I do get a blank response with 200 OK
            })

server.listen(process.argv[2]);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var http =require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var through = require('through2');
var bunyan = require('bunyan');

var log = bunyan.createLogger({ name: 'http' });

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  // log.info({'req: ': req});
  if(req.method==='POST') {
    var dataUpper = {};

    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
      var dataString = chunk.toString();
      dataUpper = dataString.toUpperCase();
      log.info({"received body data": dataUpper });
    });

    req.on('end', function() {
      res.writeHead(200, "OK", {'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
      res.end(dataUpper);
    });

  }
});


server.listen(3001, 'localhost');
console.log('listening on port 3001');
```

this should work. You can replace any log.info with a console.log style message. Never used through2.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved this one.  +1 to Evan for suggesting bunyan, I like that. I think this is a slight improvement upon Evan's solution because:

1) It uses ES6 function syntax throughout.

2) It uses [through2-map](https://www.npmjs.com/package/through2-map) to handle the burden of data chunks. It seems to be a wrapper module around through2, with a bit simpler syntax.  It takes a single function, and returns a stream, so you can use it like a middle-man stream by piping the output stream directly to your response stream.  The function you pass it takes a piece of data (your entire request I think) and lets you do work on it all at once before returning the whole result.

3) I think the handling of non-POST requests is better, by including error handling and avoiding wrapping all of your logic in a big if-block.

```
// hook up all my modules
var http = require('http')
var transformer = require('through2-map')
var bunyan = require('bunyan') // cool logger module

// locals
var listenPort = process.argv[2]
var logger = bunyan.createLogger({name: "http"})

var server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

    // check for POST method
    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
        logger.error('405: Method Not Allowed')
        res.writeHead(405)
        res.end();
    }

    // pipe the request data into the transformer...
    req.pipe(transformer((chunk) => {
        // do the transformation with the chunk
        // add a newline to avoid that weird '%' char at the end
        return (chunk + '\n').toString().toUpperCase()
    })).pipe(res)  // then pipe the result to the response stream

})

server.listen(listenPort)
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var http = require('http');
var uc = require('upper-case');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(uc("Hello World!"));
    res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Please could you include a description of why this is the answer?

Comment: You should write some description. and do not duplicate your answer.